# if an object has no entry in sys.database_permissions are all of its permissions assumed to be "GRANT"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Let's say I have a function that is accessed in many stored procedures. If that function has no entries in `sys.database_permissions` does any account that can run one of the stored procs automatically run the function?

This is the query I'm using:

```
 exec sp_depends 'dbo.theFunction' 

 -- for each object in those results, run this query

 select *  
 from sys.database_permissions dp
 where 
 grantee_principal_id=USER_ID('theAccount')
 and 
 major_id=object_id('dbo.theFunction')
 and minor_id=0
 and ( state_desc = 'GRANT' or state_desc = 'SELECT' )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is never an implicit GRANT, on anything. How the 'table accessed from stored procedure' or 'function accessed from stored procedure' works usually is through [ownership chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx):

> When multiple database objects access
>   each other sequentially, the sequence
>   is known as a chain. [...] When an object is accessed through a
>   chain, SQL Server first compares the
>   owner of the object to the owner of
>   the calling object. This is the
>   previous link in the chain. If both
>   objects have the same owner,
>   permissions on the referenced object
>   are not evaluated.

Comment: I knew it had to be something like this. Thanks for finding it, my coworkers and I were stumped about why we were seeing this behavior.